# I can not get inputs file from a put or patch request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, put

## Description:

- I can not check exist file if using `put/patch` method.
- Image description
  [The picture put method when using post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9vXy.png)

## Expected:

- I can check exist file if using put/patch method similar using post method.
- Image description
  [The picture post method when using post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXzhc.png)

## My code example:

`public function update(Request $request, $id){
      dd($request->hasFile('logo'));
    }`

Comment: Seems like a bug. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Comment: Excuse me, I still have not found the solution

Comment: Send a `POST` request and add  `_method` with  `PUT` or  `PATCH`. [see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-239451567)

Answer (score 0):

check your form's attribute . it must have  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score -1):

I can't see all of your data but make sure you are including CRSF token.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I do not think so. I do not understand why how to update images in api